# Adding Buttons to FingerPaint Android API Sample1

Tags: android, dynamic, button

Im kind of new to Android.

I am playing around with the Android FingerPaint API Sample. I have figured out how to add buttons and functions to the Menu, but how do I get buttons on the actual screen?

Is it possible to place buttons over the drawing surface? Or would I need a linear (Vertical) layout on the left, and place buttons in there. Either would be fine.

Help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Android `FingerPaint` sample code does not use a layout; it instead just has a subclass of `View` called `MyView`, and then the Activity sets its content view to be an instance of `MyView`.

If you want to have more than one `View` on the screen, you'll need to use some sort of layout. You could use a `LinearLayout` if you want the `MyView` for painting to be above, below, or to the side of the buttons; if you want the buttons to be on top of the `MyView`, take a look at using a `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.

You can either then define the layout in XML or create it manually in code. The former is more flexible and maintainable, but there will be a few hiccups.

First, create a layout XML showing how you want your components to be laid out. For this example, we'll call it `finger_paint.xml`. Make sure you have a `MyView` in there somewhere, something like:

```xml
<view class="com.example.android.apis.graphics.FingerPaint$MyView"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent">
```

Then, replace the line that looks like

```java
setContentView(new MyView(this));
```

with

```
setContentView(R.layout.finger_paint);
```

Note that because `MyView` does not (yet) have the proper constructor for being instantiated by the `LayoutInflater`, this will not work yet, so let's fix that. Add an additional import near the top of the file:

```
import android.util.AttributeSet;
```

and then add an `AttributeSet` parameter to the constructor of `MyView`:

```
public MyView(Context c, AttributeSet as) {
    super(c, as);

    // rest of constructor is same as in the sample
}
```

You will also have to change MyView to be a `static` inner class of `FingerPaint`.

You may find the [Building Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) document and the [NotePad](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html) sample useful as you figure this out.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to dynamically position your buttons?

If so, you can use [setLayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setLayoutParams%28android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29) to set the layout properties of the button.